# SimpleDate allowing null

Tags: java, simpledateformat

In my app i need to set `SimpleDateFormat` to allow null, because that input field can very well be empty.

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
                Date enddate = (Date) EndDate1.getValue();
                GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
                c.setTime(enddate );
```

The field is a `JFormattedTextField`.

```
String a = "Insert Into db (`contract_start_date`, `contract_end_date`) values" 
+ "('"  + startdate + "','" + enddate + "' )";
db.stmt.executeUpdate(a);
System.out.println(a);
```

What is the best way to make my insert accept null value?

Comment: What do you want to be `null`? `EndDate`? Hint: variable names don't start with an upper case letter in Java.

Comment: What is `SimpleDateTime`? How is this related to `SimpleDateFormat` (because your Problem is `c.setTime(EndDate)`)?

Comment: Sorry i did fix my question. Hope it is understandable now.

Answer (score 1):

If `EndDate` can be `null`, check for it.

```
Date endDate = (Date) EndDate1.getValue();
if (endDate != null) {
    GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
    c.setTime(EndDate);
}
```

Comment: That works for the check, but my question was not complete i think. Now my problem is to insert the null value into datetime field in the DB.

Comment: 'The DB', what DB are you talking about? Is this a Swing, a `SimpleDateFormat`, or a DB question?

Comment: It is a SimpleDateFormat/DB question.